# Spring-integration-jdbc. What Is the replacement for the missing attribute 'max-rows-per-poll' for 'stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Spring-integration-jdbc 5.0.6.RELEASE.
I found that 'stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter' no longer has attribute 'max-rows-per-poll'. What is the replacement for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter>` has never had a `max-rows-per-poll` option. The is a mistake in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedure-inbound-channel-adapter). I assume as a silly result of copy/paste from the regular `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` description.

Not sure why you talk about a `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter>` and that version, but it is indeed a fact that `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` now in the version `5.1` requires `max-rows` instead. Nevertheless a `max-rows-per-poll` is still there, although deprecated.

Comment: Thanx for reply and for clarifying.

Comment: Fixed like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/aac4051d683277bdf5e3d1057a42ad3b1bc31482